# Swift & Firebase - Call a function after Observe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I'm coding a chat App. I would like to update a tableViewController after an observe-function:

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

```
  Api.Message.observeStaticUserDiscussion(toId: self.user!.id!) { (message, messageId, currentId) in
     if message.notViewed! && currentId != message.fromId {
        Api.Message.updateMessageStatus(withMessage: messageId, value: false)

     }

  }
  // THIS LINE
  self.delegate?.updateMenuMessage()
```

}

My code is pretty simple, I check if messages are read or not, and if messages are not seen, I update the status for each.

Then, I can update a tableViewController (the homepage, where messages from all users are displayed).

If I include this line

```
self.delegate?.updateMenuMessage()
```

just after

```
Api.Message.updateMessageStatus(withMessage: messageId, value: false)
```

It's working, but the tableView is reloaded many times ...

I would like to have a code like that:

1. Observe if messages are not seen, and update values if needed
2. The observe function is finished, you can now reload the tableView

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach.

Adding an Observer:

```
func getNewMessage(completion: @escaping ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {

    let messagesRef: DatabaseReference = ref.child("chat").child("messages")

    messagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return
        }

        completion(snapshotValue)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Usage:

```
getNewMessage { (message) in
    addNewMessageToArray(message)
    self.updateMenuMessage()
}
```